# How to read dt_DBTIME2 with VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to read a recordset from SQL database were some field are of type time(n).
When I read a row (`recordset.Fields(n)`), VBScript stops at this field with a 'multiple step error'.

I tried to set a variable with the recordset, so:

```
Dim a
Set a = recordset.Fields(specific time column)
```

I tried to cast the field.

I tried to find any information about this specific type, but I can't find any information about this time structure, besides it contains hour, minute, second and fractional parts.

```
ReDim iArr(iColumnCount)

While Not objRecordset.EOF
    For iColumnIndex = 0 To (iColumnCount-1)
        'SQL_FIELDTYPE_TIME is a constant at top of page with value 145
        If objRecordset.Fields(iColumnIndex).Type = SQL_FIELDTYPE_TIME Then
            'Tried so much over here...
            Dim Tme, Str
            Set Tme = objRecordset.Fields.Item(iColumnIndex)

            iArr(iColumnIndex) = CStr(clDBTime(Tme).Hour)
            Set Tme = Nothing
        Else
            iArr(iColumnIndex) = objRecordset.Fields.Item(iColumnIndex)
        End If
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            fLogData("Ophalen data (" + oDB.strDatabaseNaam + ") rij " + _
                CStr(objRecordset.AbsolutePosition) + " kolom " + _
                CStr(iColumnIndex) + " mislukt: " + Err.Description)
            Err.Clear
        End If
    Next
    List.Add i, iArr
    i = i + 1
    objRecordset.MoveNext   'Next row
Wend
```

Errors I'm getting:

- Object doesn't support this property
- Multiple step error
- Type mismatch

etc. etc.

Anyone who can help me out how to read the time value from SQL in VBScript?

EDIT: solved! Cost almost 4h trial-error but there's a solution:)

Changed the SQL select statement to:

```
SELECT COL, COL,... (this are the 'usual' columns),CAST(TIMECOL -this is the time(n) column- as varchar),CAST(TIMECOL2 -this is the time(n) column- as varchar)  FROM tabel
```

And within code: `TimeValue(read value - from recordset.fields...)` (this is to change varchar back to time)

And .. it just works great!

Edit2: recordset code:

```
if iResCount > 0 and iColumnCount > 0 then
  redim iArr(iColumnCount)

  while not objRecordset.EOF
    for iColumnIndex = 0 to (iColumnCount-1)
      iArr(iColumnIndex) = objRecordset.Fields.Item(iColumnIndex)
      if Err.Number <> 0 then
        fLogData("Ophalen data ("+oDB.strDatabaseNaam+") rij "+cstr(objRecordset.AbsolutePosition)+ " kolom "+cstr(iColumnIndex)+" mislukt: "+Err.Description)
        Err.Clear
      end if
    next
    List.Add i, iArr
    i = i + 1
    objRecordset.MoveNext  'Next row
  wend
  set oResult = List'CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
end if
```

And an example of a function call:

```
'fGetRecord(DB, Table, Columns, Condition, Field to sort on, Type of sort)
fGetRecord(oHoofdDB,CONST_HDB_STR_TBL_KALENDER,CONST_HDB_STR_KAL_ID+","+CONST_HDB_STR_KAL_NAAM+",CAST("+CONST_HDB_STR_KAL_STARTIJD+" as varchar),CAST("+CONST_HDB_STR_KAL_STOPTIJD+" as varchar)",CONST_HDB_STR_KAL_NAAM+"='"+Naam+"'", "", SORTEER_OPLOPEND)
```

John